# my information is not being sent to my database

Tags: database, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a small contact me form and my information is not been sent to my db. It should update as soon as I fill the form and send the information.

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import logo from '../chavy.gif'; // immport header gif
import '../footer.css';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { db } from "../firebase/index";



export function sendMessage(
    nameInput,
    emailInput,
    messageInput
  ) {
    const messagedb = {
    message: messageInput,
    sender_email: emailInput,
    sender_name: nameInput
  };
  db.collection("Messages").add(messagedb);
}


  export default function Contact() {

  const [messageInput, setMessageInput] = React.useState("");
  const [emailInput, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [nameInput, setName] = React.useState("");

  const enables =
    messageInput.length > 0 &&
    emailInput.length > 0 &&
    nameInput.length > 0;

  return (

    <div className="App">

     <div className="header">
            <div className="logo">
              Chavy
            </div>

     <div className="menu">

     <Link className="link" activeonlywhenexact="true" to="/">
        <span className="title" style={{cursor:"pointer"}}>Home</span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
        </Link>
        <Link className="link" to="/workSection">
        <span className="title" style={{cursor:"pointer"}}>Work</span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
        </Link>
        <Link className="link" to="/contact">
        <span className="title" style={{cursor:"pointer"}}>Contact</span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
        </Link>
       </div>

    </div>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="column">
          <img src={logo} style={{height:"500px", width:"600px"}} alt="logo"/>
         </div>
         <div className="row">
         <div className="column column-10"><hr className="style-four"></hr></div>

         <form style={{margin:"60px"}} noValidate>
            <div style={{margin:"30px"}}> 
            <label htmlFor="fname" style={{fontSize:"20px", fontWeight:"200"}}>Full Name:</label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Your name:"
              value={nameInput}
              name="name"
              onChange={event => {
                const value = event.target.value;
                setName(value);
              }}
              required
              />

            <br />
            </div>
            <div style={{margin:"30px"}}> 
            <label htmlFor="lname" style={{fontSize:"20px", fontWeight:"200"}}>Email:</label>
              <br />
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Your email:"
               value={emailInput}
               name="email"
               onChange={event => {
                 const value = event.target.value;
                 setEmail(value);
               }}
               required
              />
            <br />
            </div>
            <div style={{margin:"30px"}}> 
            <label htmlFor="textarea" style={{fontSize:"20px", fontWeight:"200"}}>Message:</label>
            <br />
            <textarea id="message" placeholder="Type your message here:"
              value={messageInput}
              onChange={event => {
                const value = event.target.value;
                setMessageInput(value);
              }}
              name="message"
              required
              />
            <br />
            <button className="myButton"
             disabled={!enables}
             onClick={() =>
                sendMessage(
                    messageInput,
                    emailInput,
                    nameInput
                )
              }
            >Send Message</button>
            </div>
        </form>

         </div>
        </div>

         <hr className="style-four"></hr>

         </div>

         </div> 

  );
}
```

In my cloud firestore I have already the collections with the documents setup as:
Documents: Messages
message: String
sender_email: String
sender_name: String

However this is still not working, everytime I click the sent button it should add the object to the database as a new Document with the information written by user.

this is my firebase index.js

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "./";

var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  export const db = firebase.firestore();
```

Comment: what was an error you are facing ?

Comment: no error in console or other, but the information is not being stored in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize `firebase` correctly?

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
// ...
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) // make sure config object matches firebase project
```

And assign your firestore to `db`?

```
const db = firebase.firestore()
```

Comment: yes i did. i have my own firebase folder with the index.js file where I have my firebaseConfig.